# How to export with __declspec(dllexport) struct defined in wrapped class?

Tags: c++, dllexport

Is it possible to export a struct of an wrapped class without wrapping it (struct only contains enums and primitives)? Let say my wrapper looks like this:

**WorkerWrapper.h**

```
#ifdef TESTEXPORTDLL_EXPORTS
#define TESTEXPORTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTEXPORTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class Worker;
struct JobTypeInfo;

template class TESTEXPORTDLL_API std::unique_ptr<Worker>;

class TESTEXPORTDLL_API WorkerWrapper {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Worker> fWorker;

public:
  WorkerWrapper();
  ~WorkerWrapper();
  WorkerWrapper(WorkerWrapper&& aThat);
  WorkerWrapper& operator= (WorkerWrapper&& aThat);

  void DoJob(JobTypeInfo aTypeInfo);
};
```

The `WorkerWrapper.cpp` is regulary implemented handling `unique_ptr` by using `std::move` and it is not the reason of my question. The `Worker` class is forward declarated in `WorkerWrapper` and contains a struct which I want to export.

**Worker.h**

```
struct JobTypeInfo
{
    typedef enum
    {
        DoThis,
        DoThat,
        DoNothing
    } CalcType;
    CalcType sCalcType;

    //... primitives
};

class Worker
{
public:
    void DoJob(JobTypeInfo aTypeInfo);
};
```

What can I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it simply by extracting the struct into its own header file.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no contained methods, exporting a `struct` does nothing -- exporting a `class` means exporting all of its methods and its `typeinfo` if it contains a *vtable*.

Your export of `WorkerWrapper` in this way is also problematic, because `std::unique_ptr<Worker>` is not exported. It will work if you do not have any inline methods (including default implementations), but MSVC will give you a [warning C4251](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx).

Try to pass an interface pointer only. Virtual destructors are okay, as they call the proper deallocator.